# Flask break line subprocess stdout python3

Tags: python, linux, flask

I want to have break line while returning stdout of subprocess command :

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['ping', site, '-c', '2'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
return (out)
```

Actually I have through a web page this output **as I'm using flask**:

```
PING foo-bar (1.2.3.4) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=15.3 ms 64 bytes from 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=14.3 ms --- foo-bar ping statistics --- 2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.334/14.848/15.363/0.528 ms
```

I want output like this :

```
PING foo-bar (1.2.3.4) 56(84) bytes of data.

64 bytes from 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=16.4 ms

64 bytes from 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=13.6 ms

--- foo-bar ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 13.695/15.088/16.482/1.398 ms
```

Here is the full code for the route :

```
@app.route('/path/<action>', methods=['POST'])
def webping(action):
    if action == 'ping':
        site = request.form['site']
        r = re.match(r"^(([a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{1})|([0-9]{1}[a-zA-Z]{1})|([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]))\.([a-zA-Z]{2,6}|[a-zA-Z0-9-]{2,30}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})$", site)
        if r :
           p = subprocess.Popen(['ping', site, '-c', '2'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
           out, err = p.communicate()
           return (out.decode())
        else :
            return ('Error regex')
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python3 `p.communicate()` will return `bytes` objects. If you decode these into strings, I suspect you will see the newline characters processed the way you expect.

```
print(out.decode())
```

I'm also guessing that the newline characters were somehow removed when you placed the "actual" output in your question. In my terminal, I see raw bytes output as

```
PING foo-bar (1.2.3.4) 56(84) bytes of data.\n64 bytes...
```